# Ruby array.each with non unique integer values

Tags: arrays, ruby

We have `array = [4, 2, 9, 11, 2, 16]`

Then we have

```
indexes = []
for i in array do 
    if i > 0 then indexes << array.find_index(i) else next end 
end
```

When printing out the result it returns
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5]`

The problem is with the fourth index. It should be 4, but it's 1 and that's because index 1 and 4 of `array` have the same value (which is `2`).

Isn't `for` loop (or `.each`) supposed to go through all the elements one by one? Why is this happening? Why is it picking up second index of `array` twice?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using modern syntax. There are very few cases that `for..end` syntax is preferred. It is identical to `array.each` though more verbose and some subtle scope differences that may get you in trouble someday. The `else next` has no effect either.

Comment: `array = [0, 2, 9, 0, 2, 16]; array.each_index.reject { |i| array[i].zero? } #=> [1, 2, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.find_index` returns the first index of an element in `array` matching the passed value.

If you want the index of the value you're looking for then you should be iterating with each_with_index:

```
indexes = []
array.each_with_index do |value, index|
  indexes << index if value > 0
end
```

Or more compact (with just a single array allocation):

```
indexes = array.each_with_object([]).with_index {|(v, o), i| o << v if i > 0 }
```

Or allowing for multiple allocations:

```
indexes = array.map.with_index {|v, i| v > 0 ? i : nil }.compact
```

Or:

```
indexes.map.with_index.select {|v| v.first > 0 }.map(&:last)
```

Comment: Do you even refactor!? :) Nice one! But last answer is the most slick but you should call it on the array object `array.map.with_index.select {|v| v.first > 0 }.map(&:last)` or it just returns `[]`

Comment: Alternatively for your last example use `select { |a, _| a.positive? }`.

Answer (score 1):

Because [Array#find_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index) returns the index of the first element it finds in the array.

> Returns the index of the first object in ary such that the object is == to obj.